# Get page load times from a server without a zabbix agent (cloudflare)

Tags: zabbix

I have a zabbix setup that monitors my servers. I also have cloudflare. I have setup monitoring for all the individual servers, but I would like to setup something to monitor response time for data served via cloudflare.

It would be a simple web page load that checks for response time, but of course I can't put zabbix agent on cloudflare!

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zabbix "web scenario" has

- average download speed per second for all steps of whole scenario
- download speed per second
- response time
- response code

see https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/web_monitoring

There is also another web check, called "HTTP agent", to retrieve instead

- page headers and content

see https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/current/manual/config/items/itemtypes/http

both are executed by Zabbix Server / Proxy, no agent needed.